# Raspberry PI: PHP call python script with sudo

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, sudo, php

i'm running Nginx on my Raspberry PI with PHP 5.4.14 (fpm-fcgi). It all works well. But in one script i make a shell call using shell_exec.

```
echo shell_exec("sudo python " . $file);
```

it works well if i use the console with

```
php test.php
```

but if i use the browser to call this file the php-file will be executed but i don't get any output by the shell_exec (not even an error message).

So i hope you could help me fix this problem.

The called python file makes use of the GPIO so sudo is required, right?

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
    print "Error Importing GPIO. Did your forgot the superuser privilieges?"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(3, not GPIO.input(3))

print "New LED state is: ", GPIO.input(3)

#GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for future reference:

I found a - i my eyes - not really nice solution:

```
sudo echo "apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/php-to-execute-python-scripts-for-gpio?answertab=votes#7392).

Answer (score 0):

Mm, i have try with this two simple example:

/Scripts/test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print (str('hello world'))
```

/var/www/test.php

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('/Scripts/test.py');
?>
```

via a browser, show me "hello world"

Perhaps try this:

```
chmod a+x your_py_file.py
```

Hope that help..

Comment: i will test this, as soon as i'm back home. But still i'm missing a sudo there. Or is it not needed?

Comment: so after the `chmod` i at least got an error message. "Error Importing GPIO. Did you forgot the superuser privilieges?" this means i still have the problem with the missing sudo, due to the GPIO. I added the python code to the question above.